# Array of tuples, sum the values when the the first element is the same

Tags: arrays, ruby

I am trying to sum the elements of an array by grouping by the first element.

```
ex:
[[1, 8], [3, 16], [1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 1]]
```

should give

```
[ {1 => 10},  {3 => 16} ]
```

It is summing the values in the original array where the first element was 1 and 3. The data structures in the end result don't matter, ex: an array of arrays, an array of hash or just a hash is fine.

Some tries:

```
k = [[1, 8], [3, 16], [1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 1]]
h = {}
k.inject({}) { |(a,b)| h[a] += b}
#=>    undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass
```

Comment: The logic is not clear. How do you get that array?

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: @codeObserver actually the sum for 1 should be 10

Comment: @user3309314 you are correct. I corrected it. Thanks!

Comment: Also, I realize there is possible a better way to say the title of the question indicating what we are doing with this operation. Sounds like a very common operation while parsing data.

Comment: Your result data structure is strange. Why is this an array of hashes and not a hash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data = [[1, 8], [3, 16], [1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 1]]
data.each_with_object({}) { |(k, v), res| res[k] ||= 0; res[k] += v }
```

gives

```
{1=>10, 3=>16}
```

there is also `inject` version although it's not so laconic:

```
data.inject({}) { |res, (k, v)| res[k] ||= 0; res[k] += v; res }
```

[inject vs each_with_object](https://medium.com/@Fdel15/ruby-each-with-object-or-inject-a737bb90cdd8)

Comment: That is not what is expected.

Comment: the author says ending result's structure doesn't matter

Comment: It's not about the structure. It is about the particular value.

Comment: 8 + 0 + 1 + 1 = 10. there is a typo in the question I guess

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. There is a typo in the question. I corrected it.

Comment: I suggest a slight simplification to  `data.each_with_object({}) { |(k, v), res| res[k] = (res[k] ||= 0) + v }` or `data.each_with_object(Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = 0 }) { |(k, v), res| res[k] += v }`. Another way is `data.each_with_object({}) { |(k, v), res| res.update(k=>v) { |_,o,n| o+n } }`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland `0` is immutable, no need for long form hash initialization: `arr.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |(k, v), acc| acc[k] += v }`.

Answer (score 0):

You're pretty close, some changes are needed on your code:

```
k.inject({}) do |hash, (a, b)|
  if hash[a].nil?
    hash[a] = b
  else
    hash[a] += b
  end

  hash
end
```

First of all, you don't need the `h` variable. `#inject` accepts an argument, often called the accumulator, which you can change it for each array element and then get as the return. Since you're already passing an empty hash to inject, you don't need the variable.

Next, you have to handle the case where the key doesn't yet exist on the hash, hence the `if hash[a].nil?`. In that case, we assign the value of `b` to the hash where the key is `a`. When the key exists in the hash, we can safely sum the value.

Another thing to notice is that you are using the wrong arguments of the block. When calling `#inject`, you first receive the accumulator (in this case, the hash), then the iteration element.

Documentation for [`#inject`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject)

Answer (score 0):

```
k.group_by(&:first).transform_values {|v| v.map(&:last).sum }
```

You actually used the words "group by" in your question, but you never grouped the array in your code. Here, I first group the inner arrays by their first elements, ending up with:

```
{ 1 => [[1, 8], [1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 1]], 3 => [[3, 16]] }
```

Next, I only want the last element of all of the inner arrays, since I already know that the first is always going to be the key, so I use `Hash#transform_values` to map the two-element arrays to their last element. Lastly, I `Enumerable#sum` those numbers.